# Home page is blank but web site is accessible on Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

Context :
I had a an old working website on Wordpress but wanted to redesign it. I worked locally with Wordpress and migrated the new web site to production.
I have access to the Wordpress admin. I tried deactivated all plugins and tried changing theme but not luck.

My issue :
My home page is blank >> http://www.fabricasite.fr/
However, my home page and website is accessible here : http://www.fabricasite.fr/?123

How would you go about this? Why do you think my home page is blank? 
It doesn't look like a Php issue or plugin issue, otherwise no page would show on http://www.fabricasite.fr/?12345

Thank you so much in advance!
Pierre

Comment: http://www.fabricasite.fr/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)

Comment: your home page does not have any data to display. Check it on chrome: view-source:http://www.fabricasite.fr/

Answer (score 0):

In your console you get this

```
http://www.fabricasite.fr/ Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 503 (Service Unavailable)
```

So I guess your index is in php and that is causing your problems.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer. So I have used a maintenance plugin from Accurax and tweaked it slightly. Then removed the plugin from wordpress, however, there was still some traces of the plugin in the database and that was causing issues. I cleaned the wordpress database from Php my admin, cleared my cache and my website was back again.
Issue solved! Thank you!